# how to use sprockets imports with sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I have a application.css.scss with the following content -

```
@import bootstrap
```

Now I would like to use the [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) gem, and add the following sprokets directive to my application.css.scss file -

```
*= require chosen
```

I installed the [sprockets-sass](https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-sass) gem, and changed my application.css.scss file to -

```
@import bootstrap
//*= require chosen
```

However I dont see the chosen css appear, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using only the `@import` syntax:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
@import 'chosen'
```

The 'sass-rails' gem [instructs](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) not use the `require` syntax in SASS files.