# Undefined mixin 'formFieldState'. Rails Bootstrap 3 using Bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3, activeadmin

I downloaded the SpaceLab theme from sass-bootswatch.theblacksmithhq.com and in part of the file it has

```
// FORMS
// -----------------------------------------------------

.control-group.warning {
    @include formFieldState(#E29235, #E29235, $warningBackground);
}

.control-group.error {
    @include formFieldState(#C00, #C00, $errorBackground);
}

.control-group.success {
    @include formFieldState(#2BA949, #2BA949, $successBackground);
}

// DROPDOWNS
// -----------------------------------------------------
```

When I run `rake assets:precompile` or just put up a rails server I get this error `Undefined mixin 'formFieldState'.`
This began after I added active admin. My application.css file looks like this by the way.

```
 *= require_self
 *= require variables
 *= require base
 *= require devise
 *= require nav
 */
```

I can remove the section from the variables file and it will run but my styles look really bad almost like bootstrap is not running.

My `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

gem 'decent_exposure'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'simple_form'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'jquery-rails'

#TODO  needed for the server
gem 'mysql'

group :production do
  # needed for heroku
  #gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'

  #TODO  needed for the server
  #gem 'execjs'
  #gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'certified'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'heroku'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

If there is anything else that would help you understand please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two explanations - I think both of them apply to you:

- You have not specified a version for the 'bootstrap-sass' gem in your Gemfile. Your SpaceLab theme seems to be based on Bootstrap 2 while the current version of the 'bootstrap-sass' gem is 3.0.2.1, which ships Bootstrap 3.0.2, which is not compatible with SpaceLab (and the mixin doesn't exist anymore). Maybe you "accidentally" upgraded bootstrap-sass when installing Active Admin.
- Another problem is accessing SASS variables and mixins when using the Asset Pipeline (Sprockets), as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295059/650203). If you use `//=require` for importing stylesheets (e.g. for importing Bootstrap and your theme from separate files in your application.css) you cannot access SASS variables and mixins between files because Sprockets compiles each file separately. The only option you have is to import Bootstrap and your theme via the Sass `@import` one after another in one SASS file to make sure they're able to access each others' variables and mixins, like (just exemplarily):

  ```
  @import "spacelab-variables";
  @import "bootstrap";
  @import "spacelab-theme";
  ```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot I had updated bootstrap. Thanks for the advice on the second part but I did know that. I had combined all the spacelab files into one and had placed `@import "bootstrap";` at the top. Also had `//=require variables`