# Bootstrap and Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the official documentation for including [Twitter Bootstrap in Rails](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), and one of the item that caught me off guard was this:

> Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements
>   from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

My question is, what is the correct way to import other stylesheets? Would I create other `*.scss` files, and then use the `@import` directive to include them? That is what the documentation seems to imply. If this is the case, how do I import files that are not in the same directory as the file in which I am using the `@import` directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll benefit reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295059/1143732).

---

It's the old ["backwards compatibility"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) issue - CSS doesn't support mixins / variables, so using the manifest directive won't allow you to use a bunch of functionality.

`SCSS` is a [*preprocessor*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) which means that it runs to "compile" your SCSS files into bona-fide CSS, mixins & variables being used then deleted.

--

If you want the benefit of using `mixins` & extended functionality of `SCSS`, you'll have to make your `application` file `SCSS` (as this calls the dependents):

```
#app/assets/application.scss
@import "bootstrap" -> SCSS file
@import *           -> will call all stylesheets in /stylesheets dir (CSS or other)
```

Because the other CSS files don't need any preprocessing from SCSS, they'll just be called as-is. If you need any specific SCSS functionality, [change the file extension to `.scss`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing):

> The file extensions used on an asset determine what preprocessing is applied.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I decided to fire up a test rails application and figure this out on my own.

Yes, you use the `@import` directive to add other SCSS files.

If the SCSS file you want to add is in a different directory, provide the relative path name to the file, relative to the file in which you are using the `@import` directive.

Always remember that you don't include the `*scss` extension when using the `@import` directive. SCSS is smart enough to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I work with bootstrap-sass

1. Don't change application.css to application.scss and don't change anything in application.css at all
2. Create a file app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
3. main.scss add the following two lines

   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";