# Ruby on Rails 4: Trouble with adding Javascript files in Rails web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble adding javascript into my rails application. I've added the javascript directly into my application.html.erb file and it works just file. Here is the a script below:

//Javascript//

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();



var availableTags = [

];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});



$( "#button" ).button();
$( "#radioset" ).buttonset();



$( "#tabs" ).tabs();



$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Link to open the dialog
$( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    event.preventDefault();
});



$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
});



$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    values: [ 17, 67 ]
});



$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 20
});



$( "#spinner" ).spinner();



$( "#menu" ).menu();



$( "#tooltip" ).tooltip();



$( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu();


// Hover states on the static widgets
$( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    },
    function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    }
);
```

This was wrapped around `<script>` tags in my application.html.erb file without any problems. As soon as I created a file called theme.js and put it into "/vendor/assets/javascripts" and updated my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require theme
```

It stopped working. I tried putting the theme.js in "app/assets/javascripts" as well and it didn't work either.

This is the head of the application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="bootstrap-layout">
<head>
  <title>App</title>

  <!-- Material Design Icons  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Roboto Web Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">



  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js' %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js' %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I'm sure it is something fundamental I'm missing, I just don't know what it is. I also removed turbolinks thinking that could be the issue but, removing it didn't do anything.

Comment: M.T., you should start with this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @SzilardMagyar, I read that page but I will read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not a library but a set of custom js you should put it back into the app/assets/theme.js you had it in and not your vendor js folder.  You then don't have to require it specifically since in your application.js file you have the "require tree" statement which will automatically include all files in your assets/js folder.

Also, it's usually a good idea to wrap all of that inside of a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    all your js here...
});
```

It may be that your js is loading before the page now that you moved it into the asset pipeline at which point the DOM isn't compiled yet by the browser leaving all of your js broken.

Comment: That solved my problem. I need to dig deeper into this topic. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Anytime. Aside from the rails docs I found this post that really helped me a while back if you use the rails-sass gem.  Read the docs first then take the jump into @import vs require.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074173/should-i-use-import-or-manifest-files
&&

https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note